# ScriptBundle not rendering scripts that are in a VirtualDirectory

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a modular asp.net app where the modules are deployed inside virtual directories underneath the primary .net web application. We have a common module with a lot of stuff. I tried to move all of the common script files out of each client specific project into a common module.

If I create a script bundle that references files at the root level, it renders the script tag into the html.  But it won't render script tags for bundles that point to files in a sub virtual directory.

For example:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/App_Modules/Common/Scripts/jquery-1.*"));
```

no longer renders any script tag and now I get jquery errors client side.  I looked at the resultant html, and now there's no more script tag to download the jquery library.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. The root cause was that I included only minified scripts in the bundle. Once I placed in the scripts directory the uncompressed scripts, it rendered them correctly.

Comment: placing copies of min files with `min` in name resolved this for me.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately bundling doesn't yet support VirtualPathProviders so if your virtual paths are relying on a VPP to serve the resource, bundling won't be able to find them.  This is a scenario we are investigating currently and hopefully will support soon.

Comment: I do not have a virtual path provider.  I just have my web project using IIS server and there I have a virtual directory configured that points to all my common files.

Comment: @hao-kung  was this functionality supported in V1.1.0? was it done as part of this issue? http://aspnetoptimization.codeplex.com/workitem/68

Comment: Yeah this support was eventually added